# Proper way to keep WebSocket keep open

Tags: bash, websocket, systemd

so I'm running a WebSocket on my node, it's running on port 80 through Python. And the problem is when many requests are coming the WebSocket script or port 80 is being terminated. I created a checker by use of bash script and it's running every 3 mins as cron job using netcat to check if port 80 is running and if not re-run the script so my question is, is there any good method to keep websocket script running or keep port 80 running because 3 minutes is not enough since it's dying fastly. I heard about systemd service is it better than running cron job every 3 minutes? If yes can you send me some sample on how to do it. Thank you!

Using checker (bash script) via cron job, through checking port 80 on netcat if open then if not re-run the script every 3 mins but it is not enough

Answer (score 0):

It would be usefull to provide your websocket server code example. I guess you are using something like websockets + asyncio, such as this echo [server](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import asyncio
import websockets

async def echo(websocket):
    async for message in websocket:
        await websocket.send(message)

async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(echo, "localhost", 80):
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

asyncio.run(main())
```

Using systemd can be usefull for you since your server is crushing. You can setup your script to be run as a service possibly with watchdog timeout, you can check some conditions on timer and use sdnotify to keep the watchdog from restarting your service while it is running properly.

Comment: It's a long script so I pasted it in pastebin. https://pastebin.com/raw/Up0U3BZd

Comment: Well I spent some time checking the code for most obvious mistakes, but did not found anything so far. Hope you have good reason to use use socket library directly and parsing all that stuff manually. This approach itself may lead you to a lot of bugs, stability issues. If you are sure you want to keep handling socket library I suggest to run through your code and put some logs to your exceptions. You may want to consider different approach such as using websockets library or https://socket.io/ where your code 260 line code would shrink into a few lines.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue. I created a systemd with of course still same checker that is running every 10 secs. Now I'm gonna observe if this will be good